# Java randomize and return an array from a function

Tags: java, arrays

I have this function.

```
public static int[] createArray(){
    int[] array = new int[5];
    array = {5, 6, 8, 10, 0};
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array));
    return array;
}
```

It seems I can't get the array randomized by collection directly. How can I randomize and return the array properly?

Comment: `Arrays.asList(array)` makes a copy of the array

Answer (score 1):

First collect the array to a `List`, then shuffle it and return the elements as an `int[]`. Something like,

```
public static int[] createArray() {
    int[] array = { 5, 6, 8, 10, 0 };
    List<Integer> al = IntStream.of(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.shuffle(al);
    return al.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store a reference to the list before you shuffle and also note that `Arrays.asList(array)` will yield a `List<int[]>` which is not what you want.

Here is one way to go about it:

```
 static int[] createArray(){
      int[] array = {5, 6, 8, 10, 0};
      List<Integer> temp = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
      Collections.shuffle(temp);
      return temp.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
}
```

Comment: I keep getting "The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer>"

Comment: @NooglersBIT make sure you're using `java.util.List;`.

Comment: yep, I do have it

Comment: @NooglersBIT well, it's working on my IDE and on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/DkHqBm) as well.

Comment: I am using Java compiler version 1.7. Is the problem due to this?

Comment: Yup, the code in my answer is only as of JDK8. You may want to see the suggested duplicate on your post as those show solutions for JDK7.